# How can you check if data is from local or network with FirebaseUI?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I implement this library on my project https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android.

How to check if result from data it's from local or network?

I need identify if result it's from network to set animate on textView.

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem. Please describe why you need this and what you would do with the information if you had it. Why do you not want to animate on the local cache?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know whether a value comes from the local cache (either in memory or disk) or from the server. You should instead write your app to treat the values as the best guess at the current value.

If you want to know if your app is currently connected to the Firebase Database server, you can [detect the connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) by listening for the `.info/connected` value.